how to make chartjs-plugin-colorschemes 0.4.0 work with Chart.js v4.4.3
basically im doing everything like written in the doc, so
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes"></script>

and then
  options: {
    plugins: {
      colorschemes: {
        scheme: 'brewer.Paired12'
      }
    }
  }

And im having below error:
Uncaught TypeError: f.defaults.global is undefined
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes:7
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes:7
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes:7
chartjs-plugin-colorschemes:7:39729
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes:7
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes:7
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes:7

What am i doing wrong?
here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/p4eLrh8f/9/

Your fiddle is working for me. Maybe it is a browser/extension/blocking issue or something?

well it "works" for me too, the error is displayed only in the browser console (not fiddle console). but what colors do you see it to use? for me it uses the default chart.js colors, and it should use brewer.Paired12 from https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes/colorchart.html

I understand the issue now, thanks. Looks like  chartjs-plugin-colorschemes does not work with ChartJS 3.x.x and older - https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes/issues/33. Maybe you can try to use the fork with fix from this issue (https://github.com/zsu/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes). Or fix error by adding Chart.default.globals after loading chartjs but before loading colorscheme plugin

indeed - it seems the project is dead.

ok, turns out this project seems dead (no releases for 5 yrs, and no commits since 3 yrs). There is a still maintained fork:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hw-chartjs-plugin-colorschemes
so its enought to just use this CDN:
https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/hw-chartjs-plugin-colorschemes
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hw-chartjs-plugin-colorschemes@0.5.4/dist/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes.min.js"></script>

and now the fiddle is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/p4eLrh8f/10/
